# How can I pass an array into Authorize in ASP.NET Web-API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I created this class to override the AuthorizeAttribute check on my controllers:

```
public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string claimType;
    private int[] claimAllowedValues;

    public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(string type, int[] allowedValues)
    {
        this.claimType = type;
        this.claimAllowedValues = allowedValues;
    }
}
```

But when I try to use it like this I get an error:

```
[ClaimsAuthorize("Role",[1,2,3])]
```

Invalid expression `[`

It seems I cannot pass an array of integers in as the second argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the following syntax?

```
[ClaimsAuthorize("Role", new[]{ 1, 2, 3} )]
```

Comment: Thanks. That works so I will accept your question. Thinking more about this maybe there is another way I can do this that would look cleaner. I will open up another question to ask about this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the array and pass it to your constructor,  so something like this should work

`new [] {1,2,3}`

Hope this helps